# How to access an MFC control from a worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

What is the best way to access an MFC control from a worker thread?

What is the MFC idiomatic way of accessing a control?

I read here http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm the following approach but I do not like very much the `new` of the `CString`, how can I be sure the `CString` will be properly `deleted`?

```
typedef struct tagTP
{
   HWND hwnd;
   int n;
} TP;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialog)
   // ...
   ON_MESSAGE( UWM_UPDATE_RESULTS, OnUpdateResults )
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedDoWork()
{
   TP* tp = new TP;
   tp->hwnd = m_hWnd;
   tp->n = 42;

   AfxBeginThread( doWork, tp );
}

UINT CMyDlg::doWork(LPVOID p)
{
   TP* tp = reinterpret_cast< TP* >(p);
   CWnd* dlg = FromHandle( tp->hwnd );

   if ( tp->n == 42 ) {   
      CString* s = new CString( "Is the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything" );
      dlg->PostMessage( UWM_UPDATE_STATUS, 0, reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >(s) );
   }

   return 0;
}

LRESULT CMyDlg::OnUpdateResults(WPARAM,LPARAM lParam)
{
   CString* s = reinterpret_cast<CString *>(lParam);
   m_result.AddString( *s );// m_result is a CListBox
   delete s;
   UpdateData( FALSE );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should store the CString pointer in a smart pointer in OnUpdateResults() to ensure it's destruction in case of exceptions in your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Using [PostMessage(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tdesxec.aspx) is correct. Consider using [SendMessage(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t64sseb3.aspx) - which block until finished.
Passing a pointer to a newed object is common - check the return value of the PostMessage(..) to check whether it was posted or not.

> how can I be sure the CString will be properly deleted ?

As mentioned, check the return value of PostMessage(..) and work up the whole message queue in case of quiting the message loop.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, MFC controls can only be accessed from the thread that created them.  This is the reason why the sample you found goes through the extra step of passing a message.  The message is received and processed by the thread that created the control.

The CString is properly deleted in OnUpdateResults().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Simon's answer, if you have a more complicated scenario where it's harder to figure out who should delete the CString (or whatever type), consider std::tr1::shared_ptr.  It will take care of deleting.

Comment: You can do that before posting (and then release the pointer) and after receiving it in the message handler (assign it with a smart pointer). This is only about exception safety. You cannot post the smart pointer direct.

Comment: What `shared_ptr` would do in this case? It is a C++ object and may not be passed in just `sizeof(void*)` bytes. It must be allocated and then freed. Doesn't help at all.

Comment: @dgnorton Thank you, I am not familiar with shared_ptr, how can I use it?